# How do I connect to SQL Databases on 2 servers using node.js and mssql?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, connection-pooling

I'm hoping to create a connection pool with connections to databases on 2 different servers, with the idea of using a query that joins tables from each.

This code outputs two ConnectionPool objects that only use the 'config' of the first parameter.

```
    async function MakeConnection(config1, config2)

{
    let [dbConnectA, dbConnectB] = await Promise.all([sql.connect(config1), sql.connect(config2)]);

    console.log(dbConnectA);
    console.log(dbConnectB);

}
```

I was hoping to make two connections in one pool that I can query, not two identical pools with one connection each.

I'm new to node.js & mssql.  I've looked at the documentation regarding managing the connection pool, but it assumes a better understanding than I have and doesn't explain anything, just 'copy & paste this'.

Comment: Generally speaking connection pools are keyed on the connection string properties. If you change any of the properties in the connection string, such as the server name, username or database name, that results in those connections being in seperate pools. Why is this? One reason... could you imagine the security nightmares that would ensue if a single pool maintained connections for differently authenticated users?

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding what pools are, also the difference between the pool object and the connectionPool object. I haven't seen code where either acts like a container object containing connections. Do I just have the wrong idea entirely?